# jquery addclass removeclass onclick (not repeats events more times)

Tags: jquery, events, click, repeat

site: http://art.smartcredit.md/flowers1/

after click button: "VIEW IN A ROOM" -> "BACK TO ATWORKS" -> "VIEW IN A ROOM"(no repeat click)
after click button: "VIEW IN A ROOM" -> "BACK TO ATWORKS" -> "VIEW IN A ROOM"(no repeat click)

```
$(function(){
$('.button1').on('click', function(){
  $('div .textwidget').first().css({
    'background': 'url(http://art.smartcredit.md/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/view_in_room_couch_plant.jpg)',
    'background-size': '133%',
    'height': '520px'
  });

  $('.textwidget img').first().css({
    'transform': 'scale(0.4)',
    'transition': '1s',
    'margin-left': '-25px'
  });

  $('.button1').empty().prepend("<button class='btn btn-primary'>BACK TO ATWORK</button>");

  $('.button1').addClass('back').removeClass('button1');
// Click Button Back To Atwork
  $('.back').on('click', function(){
    $('div .textwidget').first().css({
      'background': 'none',
      'height': '100%'
    });

    $('.textwidget img').first().css({
      'transform': 'scale(1)',
      'transition': '1s',
      'margin-left': '0px'  
    }); 

    $('.back').empty().prepend("<button class='btn btn-primary'>VIEW IN A ROOM</button>");

    $('.back').addClass('button1').removeClass('back');
  });
});
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing circular class assignments, like you've used, why not hold the current state in a variable? For example:

```
// Store current state in a simple variable
var isZoomedIn = false;

$('.button1').click(function(){
    if(isZoomedIn) {
        // Zoom it out
        $('div .textwidget').first().css({
          'background': 'none',
          'height': '100%'
        });

        $('.textwidget img').first().css({
          'transform': 'scale(1)',
          'transition': '1s',
          'margin-left': '0px'  
        }); 

        $(this).text('VIEW IN A ROOM');
    }
    else {
        // Zoom it in
        $('div .textwidget').first().css({
          'background': 'url(http://art.smartcredit.md/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/view_in_room_couch_plant.jpg)',
          'background-size': '133%',
          'height': '520px'
        });

        $('.textwidget img').first().css({
          'transform': 'scale(0.4)',
          'transition': '1s',
          'margin-left': '-25px'
        });

        $(this).text('BACK TO ARTWORK');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is flawed. You're removing the class button1 but that's the click handler.

Comment: use `$("button1 button")` and dont bother changing the class at all. it becomes redundant.

Comment: I just copied + pasted his impl, I'll fix it now

Comment: Heh we all do it. I'm just grumpy cos i'd written basically the same answer up but you got there first!

Comment: Hah, the trick is to rush an answer incase there's a tired British guy on its tail as well :D